# iphone App: Send Alert message when App is running in background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

In iPhone how can we send alert message when App is running in background?

Answer (score 1):

When apps running on background you can't sent a UIAlert. Its Need UI to show a alert.
You can do by (APN)Push Notification.